# How to make a ListView cell's inherit it's text alignment match from column header?

Tags: wpf, listview

I am using a ListView with a GridView as the View. I am using a TextBlock in the cell template. I want the text alignment to match the column header - I guess it involves some kind of binding using FindAncestor, but I'm not quite sure how to get this to work. I may end wrapping the text block up in a custom control along with other things and I'd like to include the inheritance behaviour in the custom control so I don't have to keep repeating it.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Creator">
  <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
       <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="11" />
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
       <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
    </Style>
  </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Margin="-6, 0" TextAlignment="{Binding ??}" Text="{Binding Creator}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: I doubt that a cell has a column ancestor. It's more likely a descendant of a row.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Header and CellTemplate ContentAlignment to Stretch, so it can consume more space.

Then you can set the TextAligmnent as a Resource and reference it.

Example:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <TextAlignment x:Key="myTextAlignment">Right</TextAlignment>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ListView>
      <ListViewItem>Value1</ListViewItem>
      <ListViewItem>Value2</ListViewItem>
      <ListViewItem>Value3</ListViewItem>
      <ListViewItem>Value4</ListViewItem>

      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Creator">
            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Header" TextAlignment="{StaticResource myTextAlignment}"></TextBlock>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock TextAlignment="{StaticResource myTextAlignment}" Text="{Binding}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: What I am looking for is a way for the cell to "inherit" its alignment value from it's column header with having to explicitly set them both to the same value. Have ammended the question.

Comment: I don't think that this scenario is possible, that's why I suggested above way as a Resource.